# How to create a pages with different moderators in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Here I have developed a application with all required methods such as add/delete/view with more additional options but now i need to separate the pages accordingly type of users. For example user has only rights to READ and Administrator has all type access.

I ve found some solution to overcome this by session variable as role and giving access to limited methods but THE PROBLEM IS WHENEVER I ACCESS THE METHODS DIRECTLY THROUGH URL it easily accessible to all users even it is a user or admin.

How to control this access?

Comment: it seems to me you should consider the concept of a role-store this in the user profile and load it each time the user uses a controller. ie put in a call to load the user data from the database each time the constructor is run.

Answer (score 0):

An example controller method

```
public function add(){
    //only allow administrators
    if($this->session->userdata('user_type') != 'admin'){
         //do whatever you want here, redirect user to some place (login) or show an error
         $data['error'] = 'You do not have necessary permissions';
         $this->load->view('view-file', $data);
   }else{
        //ok so user is admin, now do the rest of the job
   }
}
```

The above method, you will have to check manually in each method. A better way would be to create a `MY_Controller` and have the common logic there

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function adminCheck(){
        if($this->session->userdata('user_type') != 'admin'){
            $data['error'] = 'No permission';
            $this->load->view('view-file', $data);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your normal controller methods, you can just call the function `adminCheck()`